# ADB Script via Javascript or Batch file

Tags: javascript, android, batch-file, command, adb

I am looking to create a batch / JS file that executes the below mentioned ABD commands for Android OS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
CD C:\Documents and Settings\tech\desktop\pattern\
adb shell
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databasessqlite3 settings.db
update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';
update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';
.quit
```

I am getting hung up that it will not move beyond adb shell

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it doesn't work on Windows, but give it a try (works on Linux and Mac OS X):

```
$ echo 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db <<EOF
update system set value=0 where name="lock_pattern_autolock";
EOF
exit' | adb shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CD C:\Documents and Settings\tech\desktop\pattern\
adb shell "cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databasessqlite3 settings.db; update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock'; update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently';"
```

Comment: Hmmm. It seems to attempt to execute the command, does go into adb shell but does not complete.

Comment: @Greg: If `update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock';` is supposed to be a sqlite3 command, you need to actually run that from inside `sqlite3`.

Comment: I see. How would I go about that? Sorry was asked to work on this and it is not my cup o' tea.

Comment: @Greg: See dtmilano's answer. You'll have to convert that into a Windows batch file.